# Moon position discrepancy between R package mooncalc and mooncalc.org

Tags: r, astronomy

I'm trying to use the R package suncalc to determine the azimuth of the moon for a particular time and place. It seems to work, but I did a sanity check using the mooncalc webpage, and I get similar but different results.

For example:

```
library(suncalc)
library(lubridate)

date = ymd_hms("2017-03-14 08:00:00")
lat = 34.99
lon = -97.55

mp <- getMoonPosition(date=date, lat = lat, lon = lon)

azRadians <- mp$azimuth #azimuth in radians. 0 = south, positive to the west
azDegrees <- 180 + mp$azimuth*180/pi #azimuth in degrees from North (0) going clockwise
azDegrees
```

The result is 178.1665. The same information applied to mooncalc.org is 180.69. the difference is not huge, but it is unsettling. I'd like to say my application will be accurate to within a degree.

Can anyone help be figure out this discrepancy? I checked a third source (https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/solpos/sampa.html) and it agreed with the mooncalc.org website. It looks like the webcalc package just provides wrappers for functions in another language (javascript?), so that's where my diagnostic ability ends.

Comment: Contact the package maintainer `maintainer("suncalc")`.

Comment: The `suncalc` package has all of its math (plus citation for the formula it uses) viewable in source code, [here](https://github.com/datastorm-open/suncalc/blob/1e12d4881a5bcb2c8a0916e3ea6d7d2b550b4503/R/calcFunctions.R#L185).  Voting to close, as this isn't really a coding question.

Comment: @birdy448 In this case, we recommend you to open an issue on https://github.com/datastorm-open/suncalc/issues

Comment: I may contact the maintainer and or open an issue on GitHub, but I don't think much is going on with this package. There are four open issues dating back to 2019. Thanks Andrew for pointing out the source code I missed. I can use this to see how delineation and right ascension are calculated and compare results with other methods and packages. Not sure what qualifies as a coding question tho.